# Restore Sql Database having Locks

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `mdf and ldf` files, when attaching them, its gives me the error.

```
Unable to open the physical file ".MDF". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider).
```

Some type of locks exists there, don't know Locks are on `Hard Drive` or `.mdf and .ldf` files.

I also have `.bak` file, while restoring it, it gives below error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
```

Comment: These files are usually secured by the DB. I am sure this is locked on file/folder level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run SQL Server Management Studio as an Administrator. (right click-> run as administrator)

Comment: or could be a corrupt .bak file.

Answer (score 1):

Your bakup may me corrupt

1. To check the SQL Server 2000 database integrity, run the command
   "DBCC CHECKDB(database_name)" on the SQL Server 2000 instance.
2. If DBCC CHECKDB execution print no error, try to backup and restore
   the database again.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b31115a4-64d8-4186-84a9-591faf976066/could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-data-movement?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)